# How do you make an inspector element that relies on variables set in the inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to setup simple inspector controls to adjust a max, min, and current variable, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how I could prevent the max value from being set below the min, or how to prevent the current value from being set outside the min-max range. I tried setting the variables to `static` to get rid of the "object reference not set to an instance of an object" problem, but that only replaced the error with a new one: "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type". Here's the code I have:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "NewOptic", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/Optic", order = 1)]
public class Optics : ScriptableObject
{
    [Min(0)]
    public float minFOV;
    [Min(minFOV)]
    public float maxFOV;
    [Range(minFOV, maxFOV)]
    public float currentFOV;
}
```

Comment: Use [MonoBehaviour.OnValidate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html) to validate your object's state.

Comment: Short answer: You can't, unless you implement a Custom `Editor` or `Property` drawer for this. You could use [`MinMax Range`](https://gist.github.com/EmpireWorld/f0f518f8b0ca84224e682532cf39214d) or other similar implementations of [`EditorGUILayout.MinMaxRange`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.MinMaxSlider.html) ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with 3 different approaches:

1.Use **const**, instead of static variables.

```
public class Optics : ScriptableObject
{
    public const float minFOV = 0;
    [Min(minFOV)]//this Min() doesn't really makes sense now, but anyway
    public const float maxFOV = 5;
    [Range(minFOV, maxFOV)]
    public float currentFOV;
}
```

2.Use **properties**, to see errors on runtime:

```
public class Optics : ScriptableObject
{
    public const float minFOV = 0;
    public const float maxFOV = 5;
    [Range(minFOV, maxFOV)]
    private float _currentFOV;
    public float currentFOV
    {
        get => _currentFOV;
        set
        {
            if (value > maxFOV || value < minFOV)
                Debug.Log("ERROR");
            else
                _currentFOV = value;
        }
    }
}
```

3.Emanuel's idea, which is quite correct except for one thing, you don't need `MonoBehaviour`, cause `ScriptableObjects` also have **`OnValidate`** method.